# How do I use Outlook macro to search for strings between characters?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am trying to go through all mails in a folder and create a new mail, to an address specified in the first mail.

I need to search through the body of the email for the following: <*email@address.com*> and copy the email address between the two angle brackets to use it as the recipient for the new email.

Comment: Could you simply use wildcards?  This statement `<employee_name@work.com>" Like "<*@*.com>"` evaluates to `True`, so you could use a Range.Find approach to check for: `<*@*.*>` and continue until you've exhausted the document's text?  If you need something more robust you could probably use RegEx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to find out where the < and > sign ist and choose the text inbetween:

NOT TESTED

```
dim start_str as integer
dim end_str as integer
dim mymail as string
start_str = instr(mailitem.body,"<") + 1
end_str = instr(mailitem.body,">") - start_str
mymail = mid(mailitem.body, start_str, end_str)
```

I am not quite sure you might hsve to add +1 or -1 in the start- or end-string, but otherwise it should work.
You only have a Problem, if the characters < or > are exist in the mail another time befor the mail-address.

I hope this helps,
Max

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply, but this works perfectly! Thanks a lot :)